# unclickable reblog button in tumblr (in pop up window)

Tags: c#, selenium, tumblr, bots

so I'm trying to create a bot for tumblr, but I just can't click the reblog button (the one in the Iframe in popup post). I've searched the internet for a solution but without any luck, and now I don't know what to do.
here are the methods I've tried:

```
IWebElement a = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body[@id='search_actions_search']/div[9]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/button"));
a.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

then I used this one

```
_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body[@id='search_actions_search']/div[9]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/button")).Click();
```

and I used also this

```
var jsclick3 = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body[@id='search_actions_search']/div[9]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/button"));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = _driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
if (js != null) js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", jsclick3);
```

so people can anyone tell me how to get that button to be clicked!!?  and thanks.

Comment: Since it is a popup, you need to switch your driver to the current popup window to interact with it.

Comment: @Shah I apologies I know I said pop up, but it's more an Iframe in pop up. so it appears inside the current tab and not in a new window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use implicitwait or explicitwait to wait for the webdriver to load the newly added html elements, because the dialog box was added later by javascript.

```
Thread.Sleep(15000);
//or 
_driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it is an iframe, you can still do it almost the same way as switching to new window. Here is a sample code which explains the use of it (However the code is in Java but gives a clear idea):

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp");

        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='topnav']/div[1]/div[1]/a[4]")).click();
```

Please note that you need to find find out the index number of the correct iframe in order to switch to it and do stuff.

Comment: `_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.tumblr.com/reblog/134664971610/Laii3g6I");
_driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("#dashboard_posts_editing > div.post-forms-modal > div > div > div > div > div.post-form.post-form--photo > div.post-container > div > div.post-form--bottom > div.post-form--controls > div > div.control.left > button")).Click();` I wrote this but it didn't work, you think you can checkout tumblr and see what I mean with that iframe. thanks

Comment: I am trying from a long time but tumblr server is having some serious issues :/

Comment: I don't understand, when I use the IMacros tumblr shows no issues at all. it can locate the Iframe and click anything you want.